# Free Assignment: Longest Word Worth a Million

Tags: word, calculation-puzzle

This is very much inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91026/longest-word-worth-at-most-a-million).

> Take the first 26 primes and relate each one to a letter of the alphabet.
>   On this occasion, you may choose how each number is mapped to each letter (so, for example we may have A=67, B=31, etc) but each letter must be mapped to a distinct prime.
>   The score of a word is the product of the primes corresponding to the letters (so if we mapped A=31, L=3 then the score of ALL is 31x3x3 = 279)

**What is the longest word which scores at most 1,000,000 for some mapping?**

Comment: when you say 1000000, is it the sum / product /  concatenate of the numbers;  If i map the the letter A to 2 and L to 3, do "ALL" = 233, 18 or 8?

Comment: @Alex My apologies, I've edited to include the scoring of a word. It follows the same rule as the linked question.

Comment: Thanks hexomino, so the only difference from the Origin question is that you can freely assign the letters to the primes

Comment: @Alex yes, that's right.

Comment: What counts as a word, exactly? (Which dictionary?)

Comment: @Deusovi You can see the answer below which is also what I found (using a couple of very large dictionaries), I would be very surprised if there is anything better.

Comment: @Deusovi Also, for words longer than this, you can put some very tight restrictions of the number of distinct letters and the number of repetitions of each letter which is not a proof but a very convincing argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps not best, but it has to be close:

> senselessness  (13 letters)
>  s=2, e=3, n=5, l=7
>  2^6 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7 = 907,200

Comment: Computerized search of a dictionary of ~120k commonish words doesn't find anything better. [EDITED to add:] Or anything else equally good.

Comment: Great answer, this is also what I found and, like Gareth, no words match it. I will refrain from green-ticking for a little while, just in case, but I'm pretty sure this is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> Mississippi

assignment:

> m = 7
>  i = 2
>  s = 3
>  p = 5

result:

> product = 75600
>  length = 11