# Highest scoring words based on distance travelled along the alphabet

Tags: word, calculation-puzzle

For any word we define it's alphabetic distance to be the total amount of places in the alphabet you need to traverse between each letter.

Example: WORD has a score of 25

- 8 character distance between W and O
- 3 character distance between O and R
- 14 character distance between R and D

which totals to 25.

This puzzle is to find the highest scoring English words (at least according to https://www.merriam-webster.com/) for a word of length N where N = 3, 4, 5, 6 (or more if you're brave enough)

For the N = 2 case its easy to see that ZA is the optimal solution. My best quick attempt for N = 3 is AYE:

- 2: ZA 25 points
- 3: AYE 44 points
- 4: ?
- 5: ?
- 6: ?

Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure you have the optimal solutions in your mind? If not, this will be flagged as too broad.

Comment: I do not but wasn't aware you needed to. Was inspired by a similar open ended question https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91026/longest-word-worth-at-most-a-million

Comment: What counts as a word, exactly? Without specifying this, this question is opinion-based.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I've added the accepted source as merriam webster for this challenge since it has been used as reference in the current answers.

Comment: Can they be trademarked? What if the words have capital letters in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slightly higher score for

N=5

> [ZAYAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zayat), 92 points

N=6

> [SAWBWA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sawbwa), 104 points

Comment: Amazing finds! I've tightened up what defines a word in the question which disqualifies the N=5 but that N=6 will take some beating. Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

I used the dictionary found at this github link: https://github.com/dwyl/english-words. I took a text file form the github link that had 370099 words in it and wrote an R script that calculates the score for every word in the list, and the rest was just a matter of filtering the results. At time of posting there was not a "no-computers" tag, though I imagine it would have been appropriate.

R function for calculating score:

```
require(stringr) #Required for strsplit function

score<-function(word){
  #Splits word into a vector of its indiidual characters and matches them
  # with the index of each letter from the built in letters vector.
  numbers<-match(strsplit(word,split="")[[1]],letters)

  #initialize your score
  sum<-0

  # for loop runs through numbers to calculate score 
  for(i in 1:(length(numbers)-1)){
    if(length(numbers)==1){sum<-0}else{
    sum<-sum+abs(numbers[i]-numbers[i+1])
    }
  }
return(sum)
}
```

Alternative N=3

> ZAX, 48 points, same score as YAY already answered.

N=5

> ZAYAT 92 points (not Merriam Webster approved)

N=6

> YAZATA 112 points (not Merriam Webster approved)

N=7

> LAYAWAY 127 points

N=8

> LAYAWAYS 133 points

N=9

> GRAVEYARD 141 points

N=10

> GRAVEYARDS 156 points

N=11

> TARATANTARA 163 points

N=12

> SCRAPERBOARD 161 points

N=13

> OVERDRAMATIZE 174 points

N=14

> BUREAUCRATIZES 191 points

N=15

> VASCULARIZATION 198 points

N=16

> PARAMETERIZATION 200 POINTS

N=17

> BUREAUCRATIZATION 218 points

Edit: More words.

N=18

> HYPERBRACHYCRANIAL 214 points

N=19

> OVERARGUMENTATIVELY 226 points (not Merriam Webster approved)

N=20

> MAGNETOHYDRODYNAMICS 210 POINTS

N=21

> iNTERNATIONALIZATIONS 204 POINTS

N=22

> HEXAHYDROXYCYCLOHEXANE 269 points (not Merriam Webster approved)

Comment: I was in the middle of doing this, but you beat me to it! Well done.

Comment: I quite like that someone did this as a software developer myself, so I wouldn't have wanted no-computers tag anyway!

Answer (score 3):

N = 3

> [YAY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yay), 48 points

N = 4

> [YAYA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yaya), 72 points

N = 5

> [YAYAS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yaya), 90 points

N = 6 (I'm sure this isn't optimal but I don't have time right now to search for something better)

> AVATAR, 97 points

Comment: Nice work. The 6 definitely looks promising. Don't know how I missed that 3 on my quick example attempt!

Answer (score 2):

N=3:

> Enter word: [zax](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zax)
>  Alphabet travel value: 48

C program to calculate alphabet travel value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int alphabet_travel(char *s)
{
    int c = 0;
    while(s[0] && s[1])
    {
        c += abs(s[1] - s[0]);
        s++;
    }
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    char s[7] = { 0 };
    fputs("Enter word: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%6s", s);
    printf("Alphabet travel value: %d\n", alphabet_travel(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 letters:

> 48: [zax](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zax), [yay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yay)

4 letters:

> 72: [yaya](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yaya)

5 letters:

> 90: [yayas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yayas)

6 letters:

> 104: [sawbwa](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sawbwa)

7 letters:

> 127: [layaway](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layaway)

8 letters:

> 133: [layaways](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layaways)

9 letters:

> 141: [graveyard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graveyard)

10 letters:

> 156: [graveyards](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graveyards)

11 letters:

> 167: [hydrazoates](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hydrazoates)

12 letters:

> 171: [vascularizes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/vascularizes)

13 letters:

> 177: [bureaucratize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bureaucratize)

14 letters:

> 191: [bureaucratizes](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bureaucratizes)

15 letters:

> 198: [vascularization](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vascularization)

16 letters:

> 203: [vascularizations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vascularizations)

17 letters:

> 218: [bureaucratization](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bureaucratization)

18 letters:

> 223: [bureaucratizations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bureaucratizations)

Answer (score -1):

N=45

> A whopping **325** points from: Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis -"A lung disease caused by inhaling very fine ash and sand dust." ---OED

Also:

> The protein referred to as "Titin" has a proper name, which is ~189,819 letters long... I would like to claim my <s>1 billion</s> 1,937,678 points for this word please.

Comment: Sorry, but Titin's score has an upper bound of 4,745,475 points, but it's less since that score would be alternating As and Zs.

Comment: I've calculated the score for Titin: 1,937,678.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks for calculating the value!

Comment: I get 319 for pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.