# Highest scoring words based on distance travelled along the alphabet v2

Tags: word, calculation-puzzle

This is a follow on from my previous word puzzle:

[Highest scoring words based on distance travelled along the alphabet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91430/highest-scoring-words-based-on-distance-travelled-along-the-alphabet)

The twist in this puzzle which opens it up a lot more is that the alphabet can be traversed in a circle.

More formally: We define the circular alphabetic distance of a word to be the total amount of letters you need to traverse between each letter where you can loop from Z back to A and you must always count the shortest route.

Example: WORD had a score of 25 in the previous puzzle but now has a score of 23

- 8 character distance between W and O
- 3 character distance between O and R
- 12 character distance between R and D

Another example of a previous optimal solution for a 2 letter word ZA now only has a score of 1!

This puzzle is to find the highest scoring words for words of length N=6,7,8 (plus any higher if you're willing).

Optimal solutions can easily be found for N=2...5:

- N=2 AN    Score 13
- N=3 NAN   Score 26
- N=4 NANA  Score 39
- N=5 RERER Score 52

My best attempts for you to beat for 6 and 7:

- N=6 COCOAS  Score 56
- N=7 VIVIDLY Score 65

While I am not against writing a program to solve this I would appreciate letting some people have a go manually before adding your computed solutions.

Answer (score 4):

6 letters

> [ANANYM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ananym) has a score of 62

7 letters

> [NAPERER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naperer) has a score of 74

8 letters

> [GUITGUIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guitguit) has a score of 83

Comment: very impressive start again! Thanks for taking part!