# Last in the alphabet on average

Tags: word

Assign each letter in a word a score corresponding to its position in the alphabet, so a=1, b=2 and so on until z=26. The total score of a word is the average score of all its letters.

What is the highest scoring word?

Words need to have a minimum of four letters ('zz' is not word as it would make this puzzle boring) and appear in a standard dictionary (in case of dispute, I will use Merriam-Webster).

Example: the word 'ball' has a score of (2+1+12+12)/4=6.75

Comment: Do you know the answer already? If not, and this is just a guessing game with potentially infinite answers, then it may be off-topic here.

Comment: @F1Krazy There are no infinite answers, the theoretical maximum is 26, making words longer doesn't really help and there are only finitely many words in merrian-webster.

Comment: Do hyphens count in the character count and is their score 0?

Comment: @hexomino Ruling it that way would be safe and presumably guarantee that the highest scoring words are without hyphens. Ignoring them in the count altogether would be the other reasonable choice I could imagine but I don't know whether this would create new top scoring words.

Comment: @quarague The [word Tom suggested](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zu-zu) in the deleted answer below would be a new high scorer if hyphens are ignored in character count.

Comment: @quarague however, it's impossible to reach 26 exactly, all you can do is inch closer and closer as if approaching an asymptote. Thus there could be theoretical infinite small improvements, unless you're willing to accept someone taking the entire Merriam-Webster dictionary and running it through a computer program, which seems not all that interesting/puzzly.

Comment: Near-duplicate of my question [Find the word with the highest normalized product of letter-prime values where A=2, B=3, C=5, ..., Z=101](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70867/find-the-word-with-the-highest-normalized-product-of-letter-prime-values-where-a)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyzzy_(computing)

Comment: [Zzyzx, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzyzx,_California)

Comment: Are answers which use words not in Merriam-Webster valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there is no [no-computer](/questions/tagged/no-computer) tag, I found these with my computer:

> [yuzu](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yuzu): 23.25 points
>  [yuzus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yuzus): 22.4 points
>  [muzzy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muzzy): 22.2 points
>  [xyst](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xyst): 22.0 points
>  [typy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typy): 21.5 points
>  [muzz](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muzz): 21.5 points
>  [xysts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xysts): 21.4 points
>  [wussy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wussy): 21.4 points

Comment: Nice, I had not come across that first word.

Comment: I mainly know the first word from the Great British Bake-Off, where it seems like there's at least one contestant each year that uses it at some point.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is the highest scoring but it would definitely be hard to beat

> [muzzy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muzzy)

which has a score of

> (13+21+26+26+25)/5 = 22.2

Comment: Nice, it is already better than the 'syzygy' with 21.17 that I had in mind.

Comment: @quarague That is what I thought of almost immediately as well - probably would've posted that as an answer if I'd gotten here earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Near-duplicate of my question [Find the word with the highest normalized product of letter-prime values where A=2, B=3, C=5, ..., Z=101](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70867/find-the-word-with-the-highest-normalized-product-of-letter-prime-values-where-a), per [the answer by @ElGuest and @peaceoutside](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70870/2349)

- 6 letter: [**ZYZZYX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyx) = 25.33
- 8 letter: [**ZYZZYZUS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyzus) = 24.25
- 7 letter: [**ZYZZYVA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyzzyva_(magazine)) = 21.571

Python code:

```
from statistics import mean
mean(ord(c)-64 for c in 'ZYZZYZUS')
24.25
```

Comment: Wikipedia shows that these are actual words but they are not in Merriam-Webster, so the accepted answer tick goes to Wallbreaker. I still upvoted.

Comment: They're all valid words, I cited definitions, and I didn't notice the restriction to Merriam-Webster. In particular the 6-letter word is [a genus of wasp, a place in California (since 1944), pop-culture, film and music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zzyzx). Sigh

Answer (score 2):

Since the question

> does not require the words to be English (although mentions Merriam-Webster), here's a German word (although it's often pejorative, but nevertheless it's included in Duden, the official Geramn dictionary): [Wutz](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wutz) (22.5 points)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more high-scoring words:

> [styx](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Styx) 22 points
>
>  [wry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wry) 22 points

Answer (score 1):

Using a Python script on `/usr/share/dict/words`, I found a few possible answers:

> If we generalise to say that the score of any letter is its Unicode codepoint minus 96, you can have `épée`, which scores 73.75. `épées`, `mêlée` and `olé` also do well.

> If this isn’t allowed, then the next best I could find is the ‘word’ `xxxv` (i.e. 35) which scores 23.5.

> Disqualifying that, the next few are `muzzy` (22.2), `wussy` (21.4), and `tizzy` (21.2).